# How do you create WCF Test Pages?

Tags: wcf

When you create a web service with ASP.NET it automatically creates a test page. How can you do the same thing with WCF web services?

Comment: +1. In WCF REST one can go to service.svc/help and see a list of the service operations, how thet are called, and use the URL to "test" the GET operations, but obviously, this is not a real test page nor you can test POST methods in the same way. Maybe the easiest way is to generate a proxy, a test project with the reference to it and call each service operations in a test method?

Comment: Clarification...ASP.NET automatically creates a *manual* test page. A better approach is for you to code an automated unit test using a common testing framework. The days of manually entering repeated data are long gone...

Comment: An automated unit test won't help you when you just need to spot-check a service call or invoke a function that has not yet been wrapped in a GUI.

Comment: @JonathanAllen and integration test can help you as you can point it to a deployed service if you want to test it and quickly get details of the test that fails.

Comment: Last time I saw someone run a integration test against production we ended up buying 2 million dollars in US Treasury bonds.

Answer (score 2):

For "regular" (i.e., SOAP) WCF services, you can use the [WCF Test Client tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to test that - there's no out-of-the-box support for a test page. For REST services, you can take a look at the codeplex project at http://wcf.codeplex.com - in the latest release it has support for a test page with which you can test the service. You can find more information about the latter at http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Introducing%20the%20WCF%20Web%20API%20Test%20Client.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider creating automated tests for your service. In addition to the unit tests you have for testing the inner workings of the service itself (right?), you can also create what some would call integration tests using the same framework. Add a Service Reference to the test project, and create a set of tests which call the operations of your service.

This is a better way to do it, in my opinion, since this is how your clients will be calling the service - through code, not through a test page.

Comment: That answer is completely off-topic. The automatically generated test page is for allowing one to execute a service with just a browser.

Comment: There _is_ no automatically generated test page. The one that ASMX services created was not useful if your service took complex parameters in any case. Creating your own tests is the only general way to test services.

Comment: +1 - it's a shame to just test something via a browser manually when you can create repeatable automated integration tests instead.